# jquery loop not working

Tags: jquery

Why does this work:

```
var m = 1;
jQuery('#div_sel'+m).click(function() { 
    jQuery('input[id="sel'+m+'"]').val('blahblah'); 
});
```

but not this:

```
var m = 1; 
while (m < 8) {
    jQuery('#div_sel'+m).click(function() { 
        jQuery('input[id="sel'+m+'"]').val('blahblah');
    });
    m += 1;
}
```

Comment: common for loop variable scoping mistake. there must be a duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange things in JavaScript "for"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150010/strange-things-in-javascript-for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the global value of m will be set to `8` when the loop finishes and when event is fired your `div` selector will be `input[id="sel'+8+'"]'`

You can use [attribute selector with wild card](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to bind event. You can get the index from the `id` by removing `div_sel` from `id` and use the index for making id of input and use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

```
jQuery('id^=div_sel]').click(function() { 
     index = this.id.replace('div_sel', '');
     jQuery('#sel'+ index).val('blahblah');
});
```