# How to suppress VB's "Iteration variable shouldn't been used in lambda expression"

Tags: vb.net, lambda, iteration, suppress-warnings

I'm working with LINQ in VB.NET and sometimes I get to a query like

```
For i = 0 To 10
  Dim num = (From n In numbers Where n Mod i = 0 Select n).First()
Next
```

and then it comes the warning "**Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable."**

I know it's not a good practice to use the iteration variable in the lambda expression, because lambda expressions are evaluated only when needed. ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227820/why-is-it-bad-to-use-a-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression) is about that)

Now my question is, how to suppress this warning in cases where the expression is evaluated in-place, with constructions like First(), Single(), ToList(), etc. (It's only a warning, but i like my code clean.)

(Declaring a local variable and passing the iteration variable to it is an option, but I'm looking for a clean solution.)

Comment: *Why* are you looking for "something else"?

Comment: In a three line block (1.For 2. DoSomething(LinqExpression) 3. Next) it's just not nice to have a fourth line `Dim localVar = iterationVar`. But is seems, that's the best option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case where the lambda is evaluated immediately, then you can safely eliminate the warning by moving the declaration of the iteration variable outside the for loop.

```
Dim i = 0
For i = 0 To 10 
 ...
```

I do want to stress though that this only works if the lambda does not escape the for loop (true for your scenario).

Also here is a detailed link to an article I wrote on this warning (why it exists, how to avoid it, etc ...)

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/07/26/closures-in-vb-part-5-looping.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's an option too. (It's not the best, but maybe there isn't a best option for this solution)