# Can anyone explain to me why using iteration variable in a lambda expression is a bad idea

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763133.aspx

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim array1 As Func(Of Integer)() = New Func(Of Integer)(4) {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To 4
            array1(i) = Function() i
        Next

        For Each funcElement In array1
            System.Console.WriteLine(funcElement())
        Next

    End Sub
End Module
```

It says the result will always be 5 namely the final value of i. How come?

They don't put the iteration variable in the "closure"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it bad to use a iteration variable in a lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227820/why-is-it-bad-to-use-a-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because lambda expressions do not execute when they are constructed but rather when they are invoked.

See the link below:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/07/26/closures-in-vb-part-5-looping.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: you mean the closure of the lambda expression all contain the same pointer to the same variable i? Is that how it works?

Comment: @JimThio: Correct. Lambdas close over *variables*, not over *values*. Note that we are changing this behaviour slightly in C# 5. I do not recall if a similar change is being made in VB.

Comment: Wow you're from microsoft? Tell Bill Gates I say hi. I am a fan.