# VB.NET Lambda expression in contextmenu getting wrong item

Tags: vb.net, lambda, contextmenu

I'd be grateful if anybody could shed some light on a problem.
I have a form showing a sales order, this has a DGV (DGVDocs) showing a list of invoices against that order. I've populated a print button with the documents and for each a submenu with Print, Preview, PDF. The lambda expressions on the submenu always pick up the last entry on the menu.

```
Private Sub create_print_menu()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ms = New ContextMenuStrip

    If dgvDocs.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim doctype As String = ""
        Dim docno As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To dgvDocs.Rows.Count - 1
            ms.Items.Add(RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) & " " & RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value))
            jc = ms.Items(ms.Items.Count - 1)
            doctype = RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
            docno = RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
            jc.DropDownItems.Add("Preview", Nothing, Function(sender, e) docPreview(doctype, docno))


        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Function docPreview(ByVal doctype As String, ByVal docno As Integer)
    If doctype.ToUpper.Contains("DESPATCH NOTE") Then
        Dim frm As New frmDespatchPreview
        frm.delnote = docno
        frm.ShowDialog()
    ElseIf doctype.ToUpper.Contains("INVOICE") Then
        Dim frm As New frmInvoicePreview
        frm.invno = docno
        frm.ShowDialog()

    End If

    Return True

    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: I don't see any lambda expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it bad to use an iteration variable in a lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227820/why-is-it-bad-to-use-an-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: @Derek: `jc.DropDownItems.Add("Preview", Nothing, Function(sender, e) docPreview(doctype, docno))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass the lambda in your loop:

```
Function(sender, e) docPreview(doctype, docno)
```

... you are not passing in a *copy* or *snapshot* of whatever value is in `doctype` and `docno` at the time of that specific loop iteration.  You are actually passing in a reference to those variables.

So, by the end of the loop, all the lambdas will effectively have a reference to whatever the last value of `doctype` and `docno` is.

To avoid this problem, make sure each lambda refers to a *different* variable reference.  This can be accomplished by declaring `doctype` and `docno` ***inside*** the loop, like this:

```
'Dim doctype As String = ""
'Dim docno As Integer = 0

For i = 0 To dgvDocs.Rows.Count - 1
    ms.Items.Add(RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) & " " & RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value))
    jc = ms.Items(ms.Items.Count - 1)
    Dim doctype As String = RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
    Dim docno As Integer = RTrim(dgvDocs.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
    jc.DropDownItems.Add("Preview", Nothing, Function(sender, e) docPreview(doctype, docno))
Next
```

**EDIT:**

Relevant article: [Closures in VB Part 5: Looping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/07/26/closures-in-vb-part-5-looping.aspx)