# Creating parallel multiple tasks with variable parameter

Tags: vb.net, task

This is a cumbersome behaviour when creating several task in a for loop:

```
Private Sub DoSomeTasks()
    For i = 1 to 3
       Dim oTest as cTest = New cTest
       Dim oTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() oTest.DoSimulation(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

This code will create all tasks with the same i value (= 3). Anyone has experienced something similar? Anyone has a clue on how to solve it?

Comment: Make a variable inside your `For` loop that equals `i` and use that instead of `i`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227820/why-is-it-bad-to-use-an-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression

Comment: There's probably a compiler warning you missed which told you what to do.