# Parallel Task resulting wrong result

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Why List of Task resulting wrong result.
Anyone can give direction?

This my code so far.

```
static string[] kk = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Parallel.For(0, 10, i => Test(i));
        //Console.ReadLine();

        foreach(string str in kk)
        {
            Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test(str));
            listTask.Add(task);
        }

        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }while(!Task.WaitAll(listTask.ToArray(),1000));

        foreach (Task<string> task in listTask)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Status.ToString() + " : " + task.Result);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

 private static string Test(string i)
        {
             return "test " + i;
        }
```

I expecting result like this:

test a
test b
test c
test d
test e
test f

But my code above resulting like this:
test f
test f
test f
test f
test f
test f

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test(str));
```

The lambda expression, which captured the `str` variable, is only evaluated when the Task is run.

In this case, the task's threads were activated once the foreach loop finished - which means `Test(str)` will be evaluated as `Test("f")` for all six calls. This happens because the foreach implementation reuses the `str` variable for all iterations, and so all six lambda expressions captured the same variable.

Try changing it to:

```
var localStr = str;
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test(localStr));
```

This will make it so that each expression captures its own local variable.

**Edit**:

This issue was fixed in C# 5: [Has foreach's use of variables been changed in C# 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112881/has-foreachs-use-of-variables-been-changed-in-c-sharp-5)

Each `foreach` iteration now gets a fresh copy of the variable.

Comment: Thanks @dcastro for your direction and explanation :)