# Different results between yield return and LINQ Select

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I always thought that these two methods were similar:

```
public static IEnumerable<Func<int>> GetFunctions()
{
     for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
         yield return new Func<int>(() => i);
}

public static IEnumerable<Func<int>> GetFunctionsLinq()
{
     return Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Func<int>(() => i));
}
```

Yet, they yield different results when converting them to a `List<Func<int>>`:

```
List<Func<int>> yieldList = GetFunctions().ToList();
List<Func<int>> linqList = GetFunctionsLinq().ToList();

foreach(var func in yieldList)
   Console.WriteLine("[YIELD] {0}", func());

Console.WriteLine("==================");

foreach(var func in linqList)
   Console.WriteLine("[LINQ] {0}", func());
```

The output is:

```
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
[YIELD] 11
==================
[LINQ] 1
[LINQ] 2
[LINQ] 3
[LINQ] 4
[LINQ] 5
[LINQ] 6
[LINQ] 7
[LINQ] 8
[LINQ] 9
[LINQ] 10
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's closure problem. You have to store the variable inside the loop to solve this problem.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var i1 = i;
    yield return new Func<int>(() => i1);
}
```

In fact `new Func<int>(() => i);` uses the exact value of counter inside loop and that's not a copy. So after the loop finishes you always get `11`, because it was the last value set to counter.

Comment: Note this has been "fixed" as of C# 5.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112881/has-foreachs-use-of-variables-been-changed-in-c-sharp-5

Comment: @juharr It was changed in `foreach` loops. `for` loops stayed the same.

Comment: @JakubLortz It's definitely Friday because my reading comprehension has dropped to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

The `i` in `for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` is the same variable in each loop, just changing value.

`() => i` is a closure. When it is called, it uses the current value of `i`, not the value that `i` had when the `Func` was created.

You first enumerate `GetFunctions` before calling the returned functions, so `i` already is 11 in each of them.

If you call the functions immediately after getting them from the enumerator, you will get the same results as with the LINQ version:

```
foreach (var f in GetFunctions())
    Console.WriteLine("[YIELD2] {0}", f());
```

Anyway, it's not a good idea to create closures over loop variables.