# Why does the compiler complain that 'not all code paths return a value' when I can clearly see that they do?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, static-analysis

I'm trying to figure out why the compiler has a problem with this function. It gives me the "Not all code paths return a value" error, however I cannot see a situation where control-flow would pass to the `if( a )` expression without `a` being true (so the `if( a )` is superfluous, but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize that).

```
public static Boolean Foo(Boolean x)
{
    Boolean a = false;
    if( x )
    {
        a = true;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            SomethingThatMightThrow();
            Assert.IsFalse( a );
            return a;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            a = true;
        }
    }

    if( a )
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

The immediate fix is to simply remove the `if( a )` guard statement completely and just `return x` immediately - but why does the compiler complain even though it should be able to statically prove all possible code paths will hit a `return` statement? Crucially, there are no loops, which are often the main reason for it failing to prove `return`-ness.

I'm using VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: What if at the end of this code _printUsage_ is false? Remember that the compiler cannot guess if at runtime your variable is always true when reach the exit point

Comment: @Steve But `printUsage` will never be false by the end of the `Main` function - if it's ever `false` then the `return` statement inside the `try{}` will have been followed.

Comment: If the variables is always set to true, why use a variable in the first place? Remove the condition, and always print the usage if you have not returned from the method yet.

Comment: And what if for some reason, in a month or a year, somebody modifies your code and `printUsage` becomes false when you check for it?

Comment: @MartinVerjans In your proposed case then yes, the compiler would be correct in asserting there is a code-path without a `return` statement. But my question is *why the compiler fails to statically-prove* the correctness of my `Main` method. I'm aware the current code structure is suboptimal, but it is still "correct".

Comment: I think you could find this article interesting http://blog.coverity.com/2013/11/06/c-reachability/#.WIMgWIWcGdI

Comment: If you know that `a` is always `true` why not remove `if` altogether?

Comment: **C# Specification 8.1 End points and reachability:** *To determine whether a particular statement or end point is reachable, the compiler performs flow analysis according to the reachability rules defined for each statement. The flow analysis takes into account the values of constant expressions (§7.19) that control the behavior of statements, but **the possible values of non-constant expressions are not considered**. In other words, for purposes of control flow analysis, **a non-constant expression of a given type is considered to have any possible value of that type**.*

Comment: Just comment of Style. You are making your code more complex in order to put a single point of exit. This is arguably discouraged. See http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104551/should-a-function-use-premature-returns-or-wrap-everything-in-if-clauses and http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from

Comment: May I point out that a **code path** is not the same as a **control flow path**...

Comment: @Mehrdad What is the difference?

Comment: @Dai: Code refers to what you wrote, flow of control (a.k.a. control flow) refers to what actually gets executed. Not everything you wrote can actually get executed. So not every path through your code is a path in the control flow. You're thinking that all control flows here return, whereas the compiler is saying not all code paths return... so you're talking about different things. (Though there are situations where the compiler ignores some code paths that it can trivially prove are not control flow paths, but that's the opposite of the question you asked and requires a different example.)

Comment: This is also a result of *Rice's theorem* I think: there will always be cases where a certain condition will always hold, but it is an undecidable problem to find these in *all* scenarios.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a supported scenario were `a` is `false` when you reach the end of your function. That scenario is when you're debugging your code and use your debugger to *set* `a` to `false`.

The C# compiler rules are by design simple. In languages that C# borrows from, the problem of functions potentially not returning anything was a problem that could not be covered by compiler warnings. There were too many false positives, therefore warnings were tweaked to only warn about the obvious cases, introducing false negatives. C#'s rules are a compromise where false positives are acceptable if they're understandable to a human familiar with the rules, and false negatives are unacceptable. You're guaranteed that if your function has a code path which doesn't return a value, the compiler detects it.

One part of those simple rules is that the values of variables aren't considered. Even if `a` is statically guaranteed to be `true`, the compiler by design cannot make use of that fact.

@PetSerAl already quoted the relevant wording in the C# language specification:

> **8.1 End points and reachability**
>
> [...]
>
> To determine whether a particular statement or end point is reachable, the compiler performs flow analysis according to the reachability rules defined for each statement. The flow analysis takes into account the values of constant expressions (§7.19) that control the behavior of statements, but the possible values of non-constant expressions are not considered. In other words, for purposes of control flow analysis, a non-constant expression of a given type is considered to have any possible value of that type.

This is part of the last currently published language spec, the one for C# 5.0. The version you're using, C# 6.0 (that's what VS2015 offers), doesn't have a published spec yet, so it's possible that the wording will be slightly different, but as your compiler has shown, effectively the same rule still applies.

Comment: This a great answer, but since this question has become so popular, you might consider improving it by referencing the relevant portion of the C# language specification. [PetSerAl already cited it in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777289/why-does-the-compiler-complain-that-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-when-i-c#comment70745748_41777289).

Comment: @CodyGray The OP is using VS2015, which implements C# 6, which as far as I know still doesn't have a language specification.

Comment: @hvd VS2015 uses whatever C# version you choose for your project, and there seems to be nothing C#6 specific in the question.

Comment: @BartoszKP No, each C# compiler to date only implements one version of the language. They have options to issue errors for new language features, but they do not have options to implement an earlier version of the spec. (The best-known example is probably the `foreach` variable change in C# 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112881/has-foreachs-use-of-variables-been-changed-in-c-sharp-5) And while there may not be anything C# 6 specific in the question, I suspect this particular bit of the spec would need changing for C# 6's `async` methods, though I can't be 100% certain.

Comment: Oh wait - `async` was a C# 5 feature, merely refined a bit in C# 6. And nothing else in C# 6 should require changes to that part of the spec...

Comment: You have a really good point about setting a to `false` using a debugger. +1

Comment: I doubt that "changing things in a debugger" is a supported scenario for language design. After all basically every guarantee of the C# language specification can be broken with a debugger (maybe not the VS one, but still). If you change the local bool to a constant member you *can* actually write code as shown and you can still jump over the return even in VS. Hijinks ensues.

Comment: @Voo Unmanaged code can break all guarantees, not just debuggers. But debuggers which work on the managed code and use the supported methods for modifying variables are supposed to be at least somewhat safe. You've given a very specific scenario where you say that isn't the case. I'll check it when I get the chance, and if you're right I'll amend my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Voo Tested now, in VS2017RC. It doesn't allow modification of constants.

Comment: @hvd I did not say modify constants (which would be impossible to do without source code if you think about it - constants are inlined after all) but "jump over the return" which is easily possible (rightclick on the line and select something like "set next address") and has the same consequences as changing the variable would have.

Comment: @Voo Ah, misunderstood the point you were making. That's possible even without any constants: `static int Main() { return 0; }` allows moving the execution point to the closing `}` before `return 0;` has executed as well. Interesting.

Comment: @hvd Yeah that was unnecessarily convoluted. I was quite surprised about support for that feature too the first time I learned about it.. it is surprisingly useful though.

Answer (score 26):

**It's run-time vs. compile-time**

Your example is far too complicated.  This won't compile either:

```
static int Test()
{
    bool f = true;
    if (f)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Not all code paths return a value
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this will:

```
static int Test()
{
    if (true)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //No error
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that whatever validation mechanisms are in place do not have sufficient logic to infer the contents of a run-time variable.  Compile-time variables are no problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think the compiler does a very simple analysis on the code and thus the return must be explicitly given.

This might look like a wrong decision, but when dealing with complex code, returned value might not be clear. So, the programmer is forced to return it.

Your example can be reduced to a minimum like this:

```
public static Int32 Main(String[] args)
{
    var printUsage = true;
    if (printUsage)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // return nothing, so compiler is not happy
}
```

while still getting the error.

**NOTE:** if you use Resharper, it will perform the analysis you want and warn you accordingly:

```
if (printUsage)         // Warning: expression is always true
```

Comment: Interesting - though according to the article that @steve linked to (by Eric Lippert, no less!) it says the compiler computes reachability using compile-time constants - so according to that article the compiler should not report any problems with your `Main` method either ( http://blog.coverity.com/2013/11/06/c-reachability/#.WIMgWIWcGdI )

Comment: @Dai `printUsage` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: What's more, even `printUsage` is declared `static readonly` class member, it will still complaint.