# C# Linq Subquery in foreach

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I have this Linq query (Foo has a DateTime variable):

```
var tableFoo = context.GetTable<Foo>();
var tableBar = context.GetTable<Bar>();

var preselect = tableFoo.Where(o => o.Name == "");

List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

foreach (Foo f in preselect) //System.InvalidCastException comes here at the second iteration (Unable to cast to DateTime)
{
    Foo foo = f;

    var subselect = tableBar.Where(o => o.Id == foo.Id);
    foreach (Bar bar in subselect)
    {
        foo.bars.Add(bar);
    }
    foos.Add(foo);
}
```

It works fine when `preselect` contains 1 object.
But if `preselect` contains more than 1 object, it won't work as expected. In the first iteration it works but in the second I get a `System.InvalidCastException`.
It has to do with the inner `subselect` because if I remove the inner foreach, it works perfectly.
I think it has to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190227/building-a-linq-query-programatically-without-local-variables-tricking-me). But I can't figure out what to change.

A subselect in the `preselect` wouldn't fit into my application architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this (I know it is not very elegant):

```
var tableFoo = context.GetTable<Foo>();
var tableBar = context.GetTable<Bar>();

var preselect = tableFoo.Where(o => o.Name == "");

List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

foreach (Foo f in preselect) //System.InvalidCastException comes here at the second iteration (Unable to cast to DateTime)
{
    Foo foo = f;

    foos.Add(foo);
}

foreach (Foo foo in foos)
{
    var subselect = tableBar.Where(o => o.Id == foo.Id);
    foreach (Bar bar in subselect)
    {
        foo.bars.Add(bar);
    }
}
```